# stripe: apply fee on specific item of a subscription

Tags: java, stripe-payments, subscription

I have a doubt about stripe subscriptions when using them with connect accounts.

I want to allow my clients to create subscriptions for a product set up by seller. I have seen how to set up the connect account and the application fee for my business, and here comes my question.

I also offer some extra service that is not related to the merchant so the price of these services should go to my business without any repercusion to the merchant but as far as i have seen the application fee goes to the subscription and not per item.

Maybe i could create 2 subscriptions to achieve this, but if i'm right it will create multiple charges on each billing cycle and same with the invoices.

Is there any way to tie several subscriptions or apply a fee to a specific subscription item?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what your asking is not supported. Your options are:

1. Create multiple subscriptions ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/multiple)), but as you noted this will involve multiple charges
2. Set an explicit `application_fee_amount` on each *Invoice* that is created, based on your business rules ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#subscription-invoices))
3. Create manual transfers for the correct amount after invoice payment events, similar to "separate charge & transfers" ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers))

Option 3 is fairly advanced, and I would not recommend it unless the first two don't meet your needs.

Comment: I think what i will do is calculate the application fee on the fly taking into account the price of the items that the fee has to apply. I feel it's a bit dirty, but probably will be the easier for me and the clients... Thanks!